# Matching the ID with another String by splitting it or using regular expression

Tags: java, regex, string, split

Below are the sample examples of string. In the below four string example, you will find `userId` as a `key` always.

```
{siteRebateSenstvty=0;1,1;2, siteRedemptChg=16;30,77;40, userId=101}
{sgmntId=1, userId=101}
{predictedCatRev=0;101;1,1;201;2, predictedOvrallRev=77;2,0;1,16;3, sitePrftblty=77;2,0;1671679, topByrGms=12345.67, usrCurncy=1, vbsTopByrGmb=167167.67, userId=101}
{zipCode=CA11 9QL, userId=101}
```

So now in my below method, I am trying to validate `str` value with `id`, I will be passing string and id to `isStringValid method`.

```
private boolean isStringValid(String str, String id) {
    boolean valid = false;

    System.out.println(str);

    return valid;
}
```

**Problem Statement:-**

Now I am trying to match `id value` with `userId value` in the above `JSON String`. Meaning if `id value is 101` then in the above `JSON String` `userId` value should also be 101. If any of them doesn't matches or userId value is not there in the string then set the `vaild boolean to false`.

What is the best way to do this problem?

I cannot do it like this-

`if(str.contains(id))` because it might be possible 101 is present as some number in any keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the id (101 in your first example) is always followed by `;` `,` or `}`, you could use:

```
String str = "{siteRebateSenstvty=0;1,1;2, siteRedemptChg=16;30,77;40, userId=101}";
String id = "101";
boolean valid = str.matches(".*userId=" + id + "[,;}]+.*");
System.out.println("valid = " + valid);
```

The `[,;}]+` part ensures that the next character is not part of the ID (so that 1015a is not considered a valid userId when you expect 101 for example).

Alternatively and probably more robust, you could use a word boundary:

```
boolean valid = str.matches(".*userId=" + id + "\\b+.*");
```

Comment: No, it won't always be followed by `;` `,` or `}`. See my fourth example of string. There will be a comma as soon as the previous value for the key is finished. So something like this- `a, b, c`

Comment: @Nevzz03 Not sure I understand - in all your examples, 101 is followed by `}`. The regex I propose will find you id if it looks like `userId=101}` or `userId=101,` or `userId=101;`. You can remove the `,` or `;` if they are not applicable.

Comment: I will always be having String like this- `a=somevalue, b=somevalue, userId=101`.

Comment: What character can be found after 101?

Comment: You said followed by. My mistake, I thought you mentioned before `userId`.

Comment: I'd use a `\b` word boundary instead of the character class you mention.